# Horizontal Scrolling when Scrollview inside Scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have two horizontal paging scroll views where a one is smaller and a subview of the the other. Is there a setup that consistently allows a horizontal drag to move the outer scroll view when there is no more paging to do in the inner scroll view?

Comment: That should be the default behaviour of nested scrollviews, although I've only ever done it with the outer scrollview being a paging scrollview. What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Its the default behaviour of ScrollView..you don't have to do anything for that.

Comment: Right now swipes to the inner scroll view seems to stay captured by it. when I reach the end, the outer scroll view does not start to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to turn off the rubberbanding in the inner scroll view for this to work properly.